# Условие с верной группировкой по 20 штук

Tags: sql, sql-server

Друзья, добрый день!

Есть проблема. Код представленный ниже, собирает данные, агрегирует их по 20 записей, потом выводит все это дело на график. Бывает такое, что данные в базу попадают некоректные ( вместо значения 550, получается 10000 ). Такие данные являются ошибочными, и на графике только все портят (т.к график строит среднее за 20 значений, и если 19 из них 550+-10, то 20 может быть 15к ) соответвенно я их пытаюсь отсеять.

Суть вопроса:
 Когда наступает условие :

```
WHEN AVG(Consumption) >  cast (Value AS Numeric(10,5)) * 1.15
```

Происходит следующее. Вместо замены 1ой ошибочной записи из 20, это условие присваивает новое значение всем 20-ти записям, что не является верным. Как сделать так, чтобы присваивалось только одной записи?

КОД:

```
SELECT



        /* DateTime =  max(DateTime)  - выбирает из 20-ки самую позднюю дату*/
        /* CASE проверяет данные на "адекватность" и если счетчик "врет" присваевает максимально адекватное значение */
           DateTime =  max(DateTime),
           OrderNo,
           ProductNo,
           Value,
           Brand,
           BrandName,
           LinkUp,
           KDF,
           StartDate,
           CompletionDate,
           ID_AVG,
           /*Так как весы очень точные, и мерием мы это все в МГ, то на данные влияет даже просто остановка машины*/
           /*По этому мы создаем условие, которое странные значения( +-15% от нормы) заменяет на VALUE*/
           CASE 
                WHEN AVG(Consumption) >  cast (Value AS Numeric(10,5)) * 1.15  
                THEN cast (Value AS Numeric(10,5)) * 1.02  
                ELSE AVG(Consumption)   
                END AS Consumption

            /*  ROUND ((ID/20),0)+1 AS ID_AVG  - разбивает все данные на 20-ки и записывает из как ID_AVG*/
            /*  Consumption   = (((Diff_Count_W/Diff_Count_AP)*1000000))   -  считатет вес 100 палочек */     
        FROM
            (SELECT      
               DateTime,
               OrderNo,
               ProductNo,
               Value,
               Brand,
               BrandName,
               LinkUp,
               KDF,
               StartDate,
               CompletionDate,
               ROUND ((ID/20),0)+1 AS ID_AVG,
               Consumption   = (((Diff_Count_W/Diff_Count_AP)*1000000)) 

                            /* Ранжируем данные по дате, присваивая им новый ID*/
                            /* А потом передаем данные во внешний SELECT, чтобы он не смешилвался с внутренним ID из других таблиц*/
                            FROM(select 
                                RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS ID,

                               Coun_W = a.Count_W,
                               DateTime=a.DateTime,

                               OrderNo = b.OrderNo,
                               ProductNo = b.ProductNo,
                               Value = b.Value,
                               Brand = b.Brand,
                               BrandName = b.BrandName,
                               LinkUp = b.LinkUp,
                               KDF= b.KDF,
                               StartDate = b.StartDate,
                               CompletionDate = b.CompletionDate,
                               a.Diff_Count_W,
                               a.Diff_Count_AP

                                                                /* Забираем все данные из двух ДБ, за смену*/
                                                                FROM (..) SelectDay1 


            )SelectDay2
            where Consumption is not NUll AND Consumption <>0 
            GROUP BY

            OrderNo,
            ProductNo,
            Value,
            Brand,
            BrandName,
            LinkUp,
            KDF,
            StartDate,
            CompletionDate,
            ID_AVG
```

Comment: оберните в еще один запрос, что во внутреннем посчиталось avg, а во внешнем уже обрезайте value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем запросе сравнивается не каждое конкретное значения `consumption` на превышение допустимого значения, а среднее значение всех 20 записей. 
Поэтому когда среднее значение 20 записей превышает значение `value*1.15` оно заменяется на `value*1.15`, а не каждое из 20 значений заменяется на это число.

Для того, чтобы работало так как Вы хотите Вам нужно заменять значения `consumption` до того, как Вы считаете среднее значение по этой колонке.

В вашем запросе, в подзапросе, вместо:

```
Consumption = (((Diff_Count_W/Diff_Count_AP)*1000000))
```

Вы можете написать:

```
Consumption = case when (((Diff_Count_W/Diff_Count_AP)*1000000)) > cast (Value AS Numeric(10,5)) * 1.15  
                   then cast (Value AS Numeric(10,5)) * 1.02  
                   else (((Diff_Count_W/Diff_Count_AP)*1000000))   
              end as Consumption
```

**Или можно** перенести вычисление `consumption` на уровень ниже, в подзапрос `SelectDay2`:

```
Consumption = (((a.Diff_Count_W/a.Diff_Count_AP)*1000000))
```

А выше оставить только:

```
case when Consumption > cast (Value AS Numeric(10,5)) * 1.15  
  then cast (Value AS Numeric(10,5)) * 1.02  
  else Consumption    
end as Consumption
```

Тогда на самый верхний уровень запроса туда, где происходит агрегация будут попадать только *нормальные* значения Consumption.

Пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/3063).